# How to deal with zeros in neural network?

Tags: r, neural-networks, tensorflow, keras

I am working on a Keras and TensorFlow in R and I try to make good predictions for a regression problem (not classification).

In my dataset there are several features and my target variable has a lot of 0 (zero) values.

I tried a different setting for this neural network but unfortunately my network can not predict zeros. Zeros are very important for my model and I can't omit them.

So, any idea how I can solve this problem and predict values with zeros ?

Comment: How important is for you the difference between $0$ and 1e-20 for example? Why in a regression problem predicting *exactly* an output value is so important? I feel that the issue here lies above the numerical problem itself.

Comment: If you have to be right when the true value is zero, why not always predict a value of $0?$

Comment: What percentage of your target values are 0? What value is your model predicting instead?

Comment: Descriptive statistics for target variable    is    (Min.   :        0   , 1st Qu.:  1255986   , Median :  1921760  , Mean   :  2374879  , 3rd Qu.:  2645579   and Max.   :114866129 ). In total in dataset of 7277 rows around 290 I have zeros. None of the predicted values has a value of zero
My model with neural network give me error of RMSE:761819.8.
Is this error large?

Comment: 3% of values being 0 doesn't seem like too many 0 values at all, and your RMSE is significantly lower than the mean of the target, so we know that the network is learning *something*. Perhaps you could use a strategy similar to a zero-inflated model and gain some traction; based on the range of values for the target, it seems like you have a wide dispersion, with most values very far from 0 and a cluster at 0. Perhaps you could [edit] to clarify why you care more about predicting 0s than predicting values closer to the mean?

Comment: Your model is probably predicting the conditional expectation, which simply is not zero in the cases you are looking at. Put differently: for certain input values, a zero may be more likely, but not guaranteed; there may be a nonzero target value for these input values. Per Dave's comment above, you could simply always predict zeros. If this course of action is unacceptable to you, then it would at least provide a good starting point for just *why* it is unacceptable. You may want to give more information as to what you are modeling and why zeros are important.

Comment: For the record, I am aware that always predicting zero probably is an unacceptable course of action. However, it will be helpful to know what exactly makes it unacceptable.